# Sitecore 7: "Clear on Index Update" not working?

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Refer to [this post](http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/02/sitecore-7-output-caching-by-index.aspx) for a description of the feature.

My HTML cache is enabled, and I have turned on "Clear on Index Update" for one of my Renderings.

However, the entry for my Rendering is NOT marked with any special token in the cache - I verified the cache content before and after using the rendering. This, of course, leads to the Clear() method in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDependentHtmlCacheManager to not pick it up, making this feature useless.

I am on Sitecore 7.2 - is this a known bug?

Comment: Is your site included in the `<sites>` section of `<event name="publish:end">` and `<event name="publish:end:remote">`?

Comment: It didn't, but even after including it nothing changed - the cache key still misses the **_#index** token.

Comment: Cache key misses **_#index** token, that's true, but in fact you don't need to worry about that part fo the key, cause the cache for the whole site should be cleared. If you really need  **_#index**  in your cache key, I've written a code which does it a long time ago and can share it with you if you need.

Comment: The point is that I would like the cache of just a specific item to be cleared when its associated index(es) are updated, to reduce the performance hit; and since this features allegedly does it out of the box without having to manually handling an event and clearing the corresponding key, I hoped I could use of it.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? The key is added to cachekey in WebForms (`Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl`) but not in MVC (`Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.GenerateCacheKey`). @MarekMusielak answer is correct for MVC.

Comment: Really? And why should that be? I am using MVC indeed. Where is it ever mentioned that it is a Forms-only option?

Comment: It's not supposed to be, so I suspect it is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that this features is currently bugged on MVC, at least as of 16th of March 2015:

http://www.tarasalenin.com/caching-sitecore-mvc-renderings/

That's about it. There are workarounds, but in the meanwhile I sorted my problem in a different way. Posting this in case someone else happens to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `GenerateCacheKey` processor (or add your own processor after that one) and update the key to include `_#index`.

Code below is for MVC. As @jammykam says, in WebForms key is added to cacheKey OOTB.

```cs
public class GenerateCustomCacheKey : GenerateCacheKey
{
    protected override string GenerateKey(Rendering rendering, RenderRenderingArgs args)
    {
        Item renderingItem = rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem;

        var key = base.GenerateKey(rendering, args);

        if (renderingItem["ClearOnIndexUpdate"].ToBool())
            key += "_#index";

        return key;
    }
}
```

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc.renderRendering>
        <processor 
          type="My.Assembly.Namespace.GenerateCustomCacheKey, My.Assembly" 
          patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.GenerateCacheKey, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </mvc.renderRendering>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```